# Geometric fibres of a spec of a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes, fibre-product

Suppose I have a morphism of schemes $f: X \to Y$, and the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$ as a scheme over $k(y)$, the residue field of $y$,  is a union of finite set of points $\operatorname{Spec} k_i$, $k_i$ finite separable over $k(y)$. Let $K$ be the algebraically closed field.

I want to deduce that this is equivalent to the geometric fibre of $y$ is a finite set of reduced points.

What I have done:  First
$$
(\bigcup_i \operatorname{Spec} k_i) \times_{\operatorname{Spec} k(y)} \operatorname{Spec} K
= \bigcup_i (\operatorname{Spec} k_i \times_{\operatorname{Spec} k(y)} \operatorname{Spec} K). 
$$
Then
$$
\operatorname{Spec} k_i \times_{\operatorname{Spec} k(y)} \operatorname{Spec} K = \operatorname{Spec} k_i \otimes_{k(y)} K = \operatorname{Spec} K
$$
From this it seems that the geometric fibre is then a disjoint union $\operatorname{Spec} K$'s, and
has nothing to do with $k_i$'s being separable, just that it is contained in $K$... I think I am missing something here. Any clarification would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your second step is false as can be seen with almost any example. For instance, $\Bbb C\otimes_\Bbb R \Bbb C$ is not even a field. As for actually solving this problem, here's a hint: consider what a finite separable extension looks like. Do you know any theorems about the form such an extension must take?

Comment: primitive element theorem... thanks, I will give it a try!